# iPhone 4 application "icon" appears Blurry and Small

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, icons, image-manipulation

I have created my iPhone .png application 'icon' (57x57 with 72 Resolution), however, when I test on my iPhone 4, the image does not appear to cover the entire icon space (a tad small in height) and is a little blurred when compared to the original.  Is this because of the high resolution display offered on the iPhone 4?  How should I edit my image, so that the device will display a clear and correctly sized icon?

Thanks in Advance,
Jeremy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new icon at 114x114. Call it `icon@2x.png` and add it to your Resources.

This will use the higher resolution icon for Retina displays.

You can see the full list of recommended icon names and sizes here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you'll have to double the amount of pixels you have: create a 114x114 image and name it Icon@2x.png.
You should have a high quality icon (512x512) already if you plan to release your app on the app store, reducing it's size should work just fine.